# BoneCP and Hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate, datasource, bonecp

I'm currently in a process to integrate BoneCP into an existing project that has Hibernate, and as I was reading BoneCP's manual, I found this:

If you are using this library directly in Hibernate **(i.e. without a DataSource, not recommended)**

and I started wondering why is this? Can someone please explain to me why is it bad to use BoneCP directly in Hibernate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a strange recommendation.

The "not recommended" advice implies not using `com.jolbox:bonecp-provider` which only contains one class [`BoneCPConnectionProvider`](https://github.com/wwadge/bonecp/blob/master/bonecp-hbnprovider/src/main/java/com/jolbox/bonecp/provider/BoneCPConnectionProvider.java).

If you want to use BoneCP with Hibernate, you will need the `bonecp-provider` because it is a required configuration property in `hibernate.cfg.xml`:

`<property name="connection.provider_class">com.jolbox.bonecp.provider.BoneCPConnectionProvider</property>`

(copied from [here](http://jolbox.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=302), but also shown in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23018179/3080094)).

If you do not use the `bonecp-provider`, you must use the "default" datasource implementation `jcom.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource` (shown in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9905871/3080094)). But then you cannot use Hibernate.